# Why can't I use jQuery functions on templated elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, template-engine

I'm using Blueimp's jQuery-file-upload plugin which uses his javascript templating engine. I can't seem to affect any of the elements rendered via the template using jQuery functions, but anything static outside of the template works as expected when targeted.

For example, I'm trying to simply add a class to an element on hover, but can't get anything out of it. No errors, no functionality.

```
$( ".template-download" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( ".deleteContainer" ).addClass( "visible" );
  }, function() {
    $( ".deleteContainer" ).removeClass( "visible" );
  }
);
```

Template code:

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}

  <div class="template-download fade">
    <div class="preview">
      {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
      {% } %}
    </div>

    <div>
      <p class="name">
        {% if (file.url) { %}
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
        {% } else { %}
          <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
        {% } %}
      </p>
      {% if (file.error) { %}
        <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
      {% } %}
    </div>

    <div>
      <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="deleteContainer hidden">
      {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
        <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </button>
      {% } else { %}
        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
          <span>Cancel</span>
        </button>
      {% } %}
    </div>

  </div>
{% } %}
</script>
```

I'm totally stumped. I've tried moving the jQuery code internally within the document, externally, wrapping it with `$(document).ready(function() {});`, loading jQuery in the head, loading jQuery at the end of the document.

Edit - [Live example](http://er.pe/list2.php)

I hope it's something simple that I just don't know about working with templates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing in the console in the developer tools?

Comment: have you tried executing your jquery code AFTER blueimp has finished rendering the template and adding it to the dom? Or use event delegation.

Comment: @PatrickEvans How do I do that?

Comment: Are you sure you must add a class visible and not toggle the class hidden to change the visibility of the container?

Comment: @friedi I've tried many different functions. What I'm really after is using draggable, but I can't get that work, so I tried to do something simple, like hover. http://er.pe/list2.php You can see the bottom image is draggable, it's a static element. All the others are templated, and I cannot affect them.

Comment: Don't know for sure how works this templating engine but looks like element are added after DOM is ready, so try using delegated event, e.g: `$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".template-download", function(){
    $(".deleteContainer").toggleClass("visible");
});`

Comment: Was the class `visible` added to the dom object? Or is there only no functionality?

Comment: @friedi no, class is not added to DOM object. Added link to live example in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".template-download", function() {
        $(".deleteContainer").toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: No dice. I really don't think it has anything to do with the jquery code itself.

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't know what that means. Can you explain how I would try that?

Comment: @Mute Looks like you cannot read any of my comments, quite funny (or frustrating) indeed... ;)

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's now with event delegation

Comment: You must be blind then ;) Read my comment under your question, code is pasted there and is similar to this posted here in answer

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. I've added the delegation code, that worked! Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why this is necessary? I'm having a really hard time making jQuery UI draggable work now that I have to use mouseenter/mouseleave. It really breaks the functionality. Why should I have to use a delegated event on templated elements?